# Can you get more than one of the same floors?

Tags: tiny-tower

Can you build more than one of the same store? I have about 6 or 7 people whose dream job is the Bar and Grill, and I only have one. Is there any way to get more of the same stores?

Answer (score 5):

Nope, you'll only ever get one of the same type of store, so the pool of new floor types is always shrinking. You can confirm this by getting one of each floor type; the game will no longer let you get any more floors of that type.